# Series IGBT connection problem that the second igbt is always on

Tags: gate-driving, igbt

I'm tring to make fast turn-on circuit, so I use boosting P/S with 19V.
And main P/S is 2V with 5A.
The circuit is as follows.
[image]

IGBT is connected by series, and gate-emitter voltages apply square function with a cycle of 1 second through function generator.
The problem is that the boosting P/S operates even if the gate voltage is applied only to the right IGBT.[image: The left IGBT gate, emitter is connected to function generator. Current measured through ampere meter. y is amp, x is sec]
Boosting P/S does not work when I disconnect the connection between the left IGBT on the  and the function generator and apply the gate voltage to the right IGBT.[image: The left IGBT gate, emitter is disconnected to function generator. Current measured through ampere meter. y is amp, x is sec]

I think it is a problem of isolation of the gate voltage driver, right?
If the isolation problem is correct, I don't know why to make an isolation.
Please tell me the reason why I should isolate gate voltage driver.

Comment: where is the common connection to the function generator? Why IGBTs for such low voltages?

Comment: @Kartman Can you tell me what the common connection is? And the reason why the IGBT voltage is low is that it is currently being tested. After the test, a higher voltage will be used.